# What citation software orders Vancouver references automatically?

Tags: citations, software

I know that MS Word can create numbered citations, but it doesn't include Vancouver style. I'm hesitant to try to install the Vancouver code on Word (not sure I have the skill to do that). I want to avoid manual references due to the problem of adding or removing citations during revisions. What citation software (hopefully free?) can handle automatic numbering and renumbering of citations? Or is installing the Vancouver code on Word not that difficult?

Comment: I don't use Word, hence a comment, but surely _any_ citation manager will be able to do this, won't it? I know many people use [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/reference-management/mendeley-cite) for example, and I would be very surprised if it cannot handle Vancouver style. I also assume that "use LaTeX instead of Word" isn't an acceptable answer, right?

Comment: [BibTeX for LaTeX supports Vancouver](https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-vancouver-vancouver/), so switching to LaTeX might be a solution.

Comment: Every citation software can do this. Zotero is an example of a widely used and free software.

Comment: Thank you very much for these replies! I will check out Zotero.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated in comments, almost any reference manager will handle Vancouver style. If you're not already familiar with LaTeX, I wouldn't recommend switching. It's a hassle if you are in a field where others do not use it frequently. And often templates that are available for journals only *sort of* work. It sounds like that may be out of your comfort zone.

Mendeley and Zotero, which is free, are common choices. EndNote integrates very well with Word and is generally flexible and user friendly. It might be the best choice if your institution has a subscription - I would not pay for it out of my own pocket, but it's nice when someone else foots the bill.